# htaccess multiple rules - paths break

Tags: .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule    ^user/([0-9]+)/?$    index.php?a=user&id=$1    [QSA,L]
RewriteRule    ^img/([0-9]+)/?$    index.php?a=img&id=$1    [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?a=$1 [QSA,L]
Options -Indexes
```

The htaccess rules are breaking the paths of the files.

Someone have an idea?

Comment: Well its doing what you are asking it to do. You want the urls to change but how to you want them to appear if not like they are currently? How are they appearing for you? And is there any other code above this block in your .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^user/([0-9]+)/?$    index.php?a=user&id=$1    [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^img/([0-9]+)/?$    index.php?a=img&id=$1    [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?a=$1 [QSA,L]
```